# Replace hostname regex

Tags: sql, regex, hostname

I need extract host name and replace it by **{HOST_NAME}**
I use this expression

```
SELECT regexp_replace(str, '[\/]{2}(.*)[\.|:]', '{HOST_NAME}', 1) from dual
str = http://localhost:8080/test
str = https://test-app.uk.ru/test
```

**Expected result:**

```
> http://localhost:8080/test -> http://{HOST_NAME}:8080/test
> https://test-app.uk.ru/test - > https://{HOST_NAME}.uk.ru/test
```

**Result:**

```
http://localhost:8080/test -> http:{HOST_NAME}8080/test
https://test-app.uk.ru/test - > https:{HOST_NAME}uk.ru/test
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SELECT regexp_replace(str, '(?<=[\/]{2})(.*)[\.|:]', '{HOST_NAME}', 1) from dual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following approach:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(str, '://[^.:]+', '://{HOST_NAME}', 1) from dual
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EQPhqs/1).

The `://[^.:]+` matches:

- `://` - a literal substring
- `[^.:]+` - 1 or more chars other than `.` and `:`

See an [online demo](http://rextester.com/GDUJB40730):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about `(?<=[\/]{2})([a-z-]{1,})(?=[\.|:])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jXxzRE/2)